# swift drawing translucent lines, how to make overlapping parts not getting darker?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a drawing app which is similar to the one here:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift

but when I set the line drawing alpha <1, when 2 lines overlaps, the overlapping parts get darker, how can I make make the overlapping part not getting darker?

Please check the image here - [when 2 drawing lines overlap, the color get darker, how can I make it to keep the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3jx3.png)

Comment: And what you expect to see if you will have intersection of two lines with different colours?

Comment: In general with this example app you can play only with blend modes for tempImageView. But blend modes can't produce expected results.
So this example can't be easily modified to achieve your aim.

Comment: forgot to mention, I send it with only one color... or let's say different colors can overlap as it is right now